# Multitenancy on Google cloud, how to obtain custom domain

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, google-cloud-dns

On Google cloud, you can use appengine api to obtain `*.appspot.com` domain. How does one obtain customer domain in an instance whereby the domains are used as namespaces in a multi tenant application.

Say `customer.example.com` points to `super-cool-app.appspot.com` via DNS configuration CNAME, during request processing how can one obtain `customer.example.com` typically servers would broadcast SERVER_NAME via headers. Does Google cloud App Engine offer such headers?

Answer (score 1):

Looking through the AppEngine Docs at

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/multitenancy/multitenancy#Java_Setting_the_current_namespace -

`NamespaceManager.getGoogleAppsNamespace()` would return the domain. The document states that this method returns blank if the App is hosted on appspot.

I've not tried this personally, but the docs look promising.

Comment: I debugged App Engine environment dumped request information and discovered that header value of `Host` contains custom domain used. `key:Host value:[custom_domain_appears_here]` I believe that is a better approach in terms of obtaining domain to be used for name spacing. In Go on could run `appengineContext := appengine.NewContext(r)`   `appengine.Namespace( appengineContext , r.Header.Get("Host"))`